# Laravel - аутентификация через сторонний сервер

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, аутентификация

Делаю приложение на Laravel и возникла следующая задача. Есть роут, который должен быть доступен только аутентифицированным пользователям. Про стандартные ларавелевские средства аутентификации/авторизации знаю, но тут немного по-другому нужно все организовать. Есть сторонний сервер, на котором хранятся юзеры (логин и пароль). Так вот, при переходе по роуту, будет открываться страница входа, на которой пользователь вводит логин и пароль. После сабмита, эти логин и пароль будут отправляться на тот сторонний сервер, который в ответ вернет true (если такие логин и пароль существуют), либо false. Если true, то происходит переход по данному роуту. При чем, если пользователь аутентифицировался 1 раз, то нужно сделать, чтобы  генерировался для него токен и какое-то время хранился, чтобы каждый раз при переходе по роуту не приходилось аутентифицироваться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать. Может есть какие-то примеры, как это можно организовать да и вообще как эту всю цепочку правильно построить. Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно следующее:

1) Создаете у себя таблицу `users` в которой будете хранить токен и связывать пользователя с удаленного сервера с вашим локальным посетителем.

2) После того как сервер сказал что всё ок, вы создаете локально пользователя с токеном или если он уже есть в базе, просто забираете его `id` из локальной базы по токену.

3) Выполняете авторизацию по `id`:

```
Auth::loginUsingId('Ваш локальный id', true); // Второй параметр отвечает за remember me
```